# Convert Map<List> to List<NewType> with new java 8 streams

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I need help using the java 8 streams API to convert

```
Map<String, List<Entry<Parameter, String>>> inputData
```

to

```
List<TestSession> testList
```

with the following test session

```
private static class TestSession {
    final String mServiceName;
    final Parameter mParam;
    final String mData;
    public TestSession(
        final String aServiceName,
        final Parameter aParameter,
        final String aData) {
        mServiceName = aServiceName;
        mParam = aParam,
        mData= aData;
    }
}
```

and

```
enum Parameter {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Baz
}
```

Lets say that input data contains the following

```
{"ABC", {{Parameter.Foo, "hello"},{Parameter.Bar, "bye"} }
{"DEF", {{Parameter.Baz, "hello1"},{Parameter.Foo, "bye1"} }
```

I would like the testList to contain

```
{
   TestSession("ABC", Parameter.Foo, "hello"), 
   TestSession("ABC", Parameter.Bar, "bye"), 
   TestSession("DEF", Parameter.Baz, "hello1"),
   TestSession("DEF", Parameter.Foo, "bye1")
}
```

The idea is that each `TestSession` is constructed using the Key from the `inputData` and the `Entry<Parameter, String>` from each of the entries in the list.

Comment: What have you already tried? What does not work? Your problem could be easily solved with [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) and [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: @Holger I saw the error this morning with the end of sentence, I fixed it up to improve the question, was that the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @johnco3: I didn’t downvote, so I can only guess. Most probably, the downvoters think you showed not enough effort trying to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Holger thanks for your input, btw I will try our your suggested answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in a [comment by the user “soon”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124464/convert-maplist-to-listnewtype-with-new-java-8-streams?noredirect=1#comment63680237_38124464), this problem can be easily solved with [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) and [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-):

```
List<TestSession> list = mapList.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(e1 -> e1.getValue().stream()
        .map(e2 -> new TestSession(e1.getKey(), e2.getKey(), e2.getValue())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the TestSession class is adapted accordingly to also include a Parameter field, you could do the following:

```
List<TestSession> result = inputData.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(
      ArrayList::new,
      (list, e1) -> e1.getValue().forEach((e2) ->
        list.add(new TestSession(e1.getKey(), e2.getKey(), e2.getValue()))),
      ArrayList::addAll);
```